# After 10 minutes background app is not close

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, background, multitasking

I am uploading some pictures to server in background. I want to close app after 10 mins. But my app is not closing, it is in pause mode in background and when I press app icon upload operation again starts in foreground. I used below code:

```
bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you.
            // stopped or ending the task outright.
            [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
            bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            // Here goes your operation
            // done!
            upload_photo();

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
                {
                    // if you don't call endBackgroundTask, the OS will exit your app.
                    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                }
            });
        });
```

My Question: How can I close my app after 10 min.(upload task complete or not)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Timer + NSOperation subclass maybe?

Comment: should I do this in "endBackgroundTask"? In Apple document they mentioned iOS will close(terminate) app automatically after 10 mins. But in my case app is in pause mode after 10 min.

Comment: Why do you want your app to be terminated? Your app is not terminated because your expiration handler is called, and it properly ends background task.

Comment: Thanks Roman for your comments. Reason: If user starts uploading bulk data and app goes in background. Even after 10 min uploading is stop but my application is still in background in pause mode. So next time when user click on app icon app start from that point( paused in background after 10 min).

Comment: Just cancel uploading in expiration handler and notify user that uploading was cancelled.

Comment: Something really terrible you could do is put `exit(0);` in your expiration handler.

Comment: Pretty sure adding exit(0) would raise some flags with the App Review team.